# SageMaker Studio & EFS

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-efs

I heard Sagemaker Studio automatically creates EFS on home directory.

1. What is the size of EFS home directory?
2. Is it possible to resize its size?

I'm a total beginner on AWS, so I'd happy if somebody answer to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Home folders of all users under a specific SageMaker Studio Domain will share the EFS  volume, though their home folders are isolated. One user cannot access the home folder of another user profile.

You don't need to manually resize EFS volume, like you similarly do with EBS. EFS volume size can automatically scale with the data stored.